# Azure Cognitive Text Analytics

Tags: azure, text-analytics-api

The new Text Analytics library working with v3.0-preview for Sentiment Analysis. I passed a text with multiple sentences as a document to get the sentiment of the whole text.

I have received the following warning in the response.
"warnings":["Sentence was truncated because it exceeded the maximum token count."]}

Comment: Could you please your code snippet to have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

Frist result on your favorite search engine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/overview#data-limits

> Maximum size of a single document:    5,120 characters as measured by
>   StringInfo.LengthInTextElements.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design: a document is split internally into sentences, but we have a maximum length limit for the number of words in a sentence.